# OpenGL: GLSL float has low precision

Tags: c++, opengl-es, glsl

I have float alpha texture that contains amplitude values. It is converted to decibels and displayed in grayscale.

Here is conversation code (C++) :

```
const float db_min = -100, db_max = 0;
float image[height][width];
for (int y = 0; y<height; ++y) {
  for (int x = 0; x<width; ++x) {
    image[y][x]= 20.f * log(a[i])/log(10.f);
    image[y][x] = (image[y][x]-db_min)/(db_max-db_min);
  }
}
```

Here is Fragment Shader (GLSL):

```
#version 120
precision highp float;
varying vec2 texcoord;
uniform sampler2D texture;
void main() {
  float value = texture2D(texture, texcoord).a;
  gl_FragColor = vec4(value, value, value, 0);
}
```

Here is a screenshot:
[image]

Looks perfect! Now, I want to write conversation in Fragment Shader itself, instead of C++:

```
#version 120
precision highp float;
varying vec2 texcoord;
uniform sampler2D texture;
const float db_min = -100., db_max = 0.;
void main() {
  float value = texture2D(texture, texcoord).a;
  value = 20. * log(value)/log(10.);
  value = (value-db_min)/(db_max-db_min);
  gl_FragColor = vec4(value, value, value, 0);
}
```

Here is a screenshot:
[image]

Why are results different? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Someone posted correct answer a minute ago , but when I refeshed the page it wasn't there (deleted?). Anyway, the problem was in texture's internal_format that needs to be GL_ALPHA32F_ARB instead of GL_ALPHA. Note, however, that in OpenGLES2 GL_ALPHA works just fine. To a person who posted the answer: please repost it. =)

Comment: I voted to undelete it. Reproduced in case you need it, "[Angew](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1782465/angew): This depends on the internal format of the texture. You must use `GL_RGBA32F` (which was an ARB extension in 2.1), or perhaps `GL_RGBA32I`, `GL_GRBA32UI`."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Limited texel precision - that could be the problem. I can guess you're keeping your (very-high-range as I understand looking at `log`) values in a 8-bit per-channel texture(e.g. RGBA8). Then you could use a floating-point format or pack your high-precision/range values to  you 4-bytes format(e.g. a fixed point).